# Lollipop not start in Genymotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have Genymotion 2.3.1 and VirtualBox 4.3.20 installed on Windows 8.1. Other Genymotion devices I have configured (4.2, 4.4) are fine but the Lollipop one will not start.

When I attempt to start it directly from VirtualBox, I get the following errors:

```
can not find system/bin/install-recovery.sh disabling flash recovery
could not open /sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present
```

[image: error log]

I changed SDK (Android tools directory) manually, but this did not help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about troubleshooting a tool. You'd be better of at their [support service](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/support/)

Comment: it's not my problem only , my friends has same problem !

Comment: That's even a better argument to knock on Genymotion's doors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I activated `Intel virtualization technology` in my `bios` settings and just update my Genymotion and VirtualBox to **Genymotion All in one version**.

after **a long time wait after genymotion's android Logo**, finally The problem solved!

Lollipop not starting from VirtualBox  but in genymotion everything is now working fine!

Answer (score 0):

on linux
I have just solved the problem by removing libdrm.so.2 from Genymotion installation dir and rebooting my computer.

If that does not work, you can try to disable GPU open drivers and enable proprietary drivers in System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be due to outdated VirtualBox version. Download and install the latest version of VirtualBox.